# flask OperationalError: no such column

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I want to create a website with flask, which has a table with links that the user put there with html form.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///home.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class links(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)
    link = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    date_added = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<link {self.id}>'

@app.route('/home', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home ():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        link_name = request.form["name"]
        link_title = request.form["title"]
        link_link = request.form["link"]
        new_link = links(name=link_name, title=link_title, link=link_link)
        
        try:
            db.session.add(new_link)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect('/home')
        except:
            return 'there was a problem'
    else:
        li = links.query.order_by(links.date_added).all()
        return render_template('home.html', li=li)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I keep getting this error message,

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: links.name

and it says that its in this line:

```
li = links.query.order_by(links.date_added).all()
```

I did some research on the internet, but I didn't find anything...
How can I fix this?

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really looks like you have not created the sqlite file, if you see at your directory of your project and you don't see a 'home.db' file than that is it.

Then open the python terminal and do this:

1. CMD with in the envirorments folder:

   ```
   >>> from app import db
   >>> db.create_all()
   >>> exit() #or ctrl + z then enter
   ```

### NOTE

If you already see the file named 'home.db' than deleted and run the above mentioned code again, this is because you may have already create the file but then you add 'name = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=True)' aftwerward.

if the above mentioned didn't solve the issue then check this line of your code:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///home.db'
```

**> to this:**

import os

```
app = Flask(__name__)

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///'+os.path.join(basedir, 'data.sqlite')
```

And then off course run the code. Also rember to delete the file  'home.db' everytime you make changes